# How to select two image view on my activity and save the image states when we click on save button

Tags: android, android-imageview

My app Features:

- Take photo from camera or picture gallery; //done
- Collection of funny stickers; //done
- Share created comical photos via email, mms etc. //done
- Save 'stickered' photos in picture gallery; //done
- Move, scale and rotate sticker images;
- In this issue.. I am facing difficulty... I can able to add but I cant able to select the stickers after sticking two or more...while i am adding two or three stickers to an image then i can't able to select stickers individually. Or by selecting the stickers are changing automatically.

Facing this issue from last one week...

Can anyone suggest me any sample example program or supported lib file?

I tried *Aviary* but it is not suitable for this application.

Below is my List of Code:

```java
     public class MyMain extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
            private static final int FROM_GALLERY = 200, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST = 201,
                    SELECT_STICK_IMAGE = 10, FROM_SAVE_LIB = 11;
            private ImageView mainImage, imgNew, imgSave, cat, stickyImage, done, flip,back,trash;
            private RelativeLayout catWangMainImgLayout, rl_mainImageBottamBar1,
            rl_mainImageBottamBar2;
            public static int width, height, imWidth;
            public OnTouchListener onTouchListenerStickImage = null;
            private Bitmap camera_thumbnail;
            static int l=0,m=0;
            Pinch pig;
            String image_id;
            ArrayList stickyItemId = new ArrayList();
            static Bitmap join;
            private LinearLayout carHead, editImage;
            private OnClickListener stickyImageListner, doneListener;
            ArrayList sticky_list = new ArrayList();
            public static int drag_x, drag_y;  
            int index = -1;
            boolean stk_in_rect = false;
            ImageView imageView_stky, imageView3;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
                setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                setContentView(R.layout.cat_wang_main);      

                Info.sticky_param = new ArrayList();

                String type = getIntent().getExtras().getString("action_type");

                DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
                getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
                Info.widthAfterZoom = Info.screenWidth = width = metrics.widthPixels;
                imWidth = width - width / 15;
                Info.screenHight = height = metrics.heightPixels;

                                stickyImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(stickyItemId.get(index).toString())));

                                stickyImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_border);
                                stickyImage.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
                                Bitmap bmap3 = loadBitmapFromView(stickyImage);

                                imageView3.setOnTouchListener(null);
                                Pinch.matrix = Info.getMat(index);

                                imageView3.setOnTouchListener(Info.onTch);
                                imageView3.setImageBitmap(bmap3);

                                imageView3.bringToFront();

                                setMainBottanEditBar();
                            }      
                        }
                        return true;
                    }
                };  

                     doneListener = new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {
                            l=0;
                            m=0;
                            imageView_stky = (ImageView) catWangMainImgLayout.getChildAt(Info.current_matrix_id+1);

                            imageView_stky.setImageBitmap(null);
                            imageView_stky.setAlpha(255);

                            stickyImage = new ImageView(CatWangMain.this);              
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Info.screenWidth, Info.screenWidth);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                            stickyImage.setLayoutParams(params);

                            stickyImage.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

                            sticky_list.add(stickyImage);

                            Bitmap bmap2 = loadBitmapFromView(stickyImage);
                            imageView_stky.setOnTouchListener(null);
                            imageView_stky.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListenerStickImage);

                            imageView_stky.setImageBitmap(bmap2);


                            setSelectStickyMode();
                            Info.addMat(Pinch.matrix,index);              

                            Pinch.editMood = false;
                            //int i =0;
                            Info.sticky_param.set(Info.current_matrix_id,new SavedStickyImageParam(Info.ceterOfX, Info.ceterOfY, Info.widthAfterZoom, Info.rotation));

                        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NotFoundException e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }

                    }
                };

            }

            void camera() {
                Context context = this;
                PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                if (packageManager.hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
                    // yes
                    Log.i("camera", "This device has camera!");
                    Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(
                            android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST);
                } else {
                    // no
                    Log.i("camera", "This device has no camera!");
                    pickImage();
                }
            }

            void pickImage() {

                Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");

                startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, FROM_GALLERY);
            }

            void createStickyImage(Bitmap bitmap, int id) {

                pig = new Pinch(this, catWangMainImgLayout);
                pig.addImage(bitmap, id);

            }
                super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

                int req = requestCode;
                switch (req) {
                case FROM_GALLERY:
                    setMainImageBg(resultCode, data);

                    break;
                case SELECT_STICK_IMAGE:
                    addStickyImage(resultCode, data); 

                    break;
                case CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST:
                    if (requestCode == CAMERA_PIC_REQUEST) {
                        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                            // data.getExtras()
                            camera_thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                            mainImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_mainImg);
                            mainImage.setImageBitmap(camera_thumbnail);

                        } else {
                            finish();
                        }
                    } else {
                    }
                    break;
                case FROM_SAVE_LIB:
                    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
                    String sd = (String) b.getString("fromSaveImag");
                    if (resultCode == 13) {
                        callDialog_SaveToLib();
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            void addStickyImage(int resultCode, Intent data){
                if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                    //sticky_param_added = false;
                    index = index +1;
                    Pinch.drag_x_value = Info.screenWidth/2;
                    Info.ceterOfX = Info.screenWidth/2;
                    Info.ceterOfY = Info.screenWidth/2;
                    Info.widthAfterZoom = Info.screenWidth;
                    Info.rotation = 0;

                    image_id = data.getStringExtra("img");
                    stickyItemId.add(image_id);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"" + Integer.parseInt(image_id), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    stickyImage = new ImageView(this);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(Info.screenWidth, Info.screenWidth);
                    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);

                    stickyImage.setLayoutParams(params);

                    stickyImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(
                            Integer.parseInt(stickyItemId.get(stickyItemId.size() - 1).toString())));
                    stickyImage.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image_border);
                    stickyImage.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

                    Bitmap bmap = loadBitmapFromView(stickyImage);

                    createStickyImage(bmap, 1);
                    setMainBottanEditBar();
                }
            }
            public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
                Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getLayoutParams().width,v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

                Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
                v.layout(0, 0, v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height);
                v.draw(c);
                return b;
            }
                      void callDialogToGoHome() {

                AlertDialog alert;
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CatWangMain.this);          
                alertBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to start over?");

                alertBuilder.setPositiveButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    }
                });          

                alertBuilder.setNegativeButton("Yes",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                        finish();
                    }
                });

                alert = alertBuilder.create();
                alert.show();
            }

            void callDialog_SaveToLib() {
                AlertDialog alertSaveLIb;
                AlertDialog.Builder alertBuilderSaveLib = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        CatWangMain.this);
                alertBuilderSaveLib.setTitle("OMG !");
                alertBuilderSaveLib.setMessage("yo! we totally saved that graphic !");
                alertBuilderSaveLib.setPositiveButton("Thanks",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {

                    }
                });
                alertSaveLIb = alertBuilderSaveLib.create();
                alertSaveLIb.show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int id = v.getId();
                switch (id) {      
                case R.id.img_new:          
                    callDialogToGoHome();
                    break;
                case R.id.img_save:
                    try {
                        mainImage.buildDrawingCache();
                        Bitmap viewBitmap1 = mainImage.getDrawingCache();

                        if (catWangMainImgLayout.getChildCount() > 1) {


                            join = madeJoinBitmap(viewBitmap1);
                        } else {
                            join = viewBitmap1;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }
           Intent intentFlip = new Intent(CatWangMain.this, SaveImage.class);
                    ByteArrayOutputStream blob = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    join.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 80 , blob);

                    byte[] bitmapdata = blob.toByteArray();
                    intentFlip.putExtra("bitmap", bitmapdata);

                    startActivityForResult(intentFlip, FROM_SAVE_LIB);

                    break;
                case R.id.img_cat:
                    Intent catWongItems = new Intent(this, CatWongStickyItems.class);
                    startActivityForResult(catWongItems, 10);

                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
            }

            private Bitmap madeJoinBitmap(Bitmap main) {
                ImageView imageView = null;
                Bitmap _bmp2 = null;
                Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(main.getWidth(), main.getHeight(), main.getConfig());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
                canvas.drawBitmap(main, new Matrix(), null);
                if (catWangMainImgLayout.getChildCount() > 1) {
                    for (int y = 0; y < sticky_list.size(); y++) {

                        imageView = (ImageView) sticky_list.get(y);
                        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                        _bmp2 = imageView.getDrawingCache();

                        if((Matrix)Info.matrixList.get(y) != null)
                        {
                            canvas.drawBitmap(_bmp2, (Matrix)Info.matrixList.get(y),null);
                        }else {
                            canvas.drawBitmap(_bmp2, new Matrix(), null);
                        }                
                    }
                }

                return bmOverlay;
            }

            void setMainBottanEditBar() {
                editImage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_edit);
                editImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                rl_mainImageBottamBar1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_bottam_bar);
                rl_mainImageBottamBar1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                rl_mainImageBottamBar2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_bottam_bar2);
                rl_mainImageBottamBar2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                carHead = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_catHead);
                carHead.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                done = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_done);
                done.setOnClickListener(doneListener);

                back = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_back);
                back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {


                        try {
                            imageView_stky = (ImageView) catWangMainImgLayout.getChildAt(Info.current_matrix_id+1);
                            if(l==0)
                            {
                                imageView_stky.setAlpha(50);

                                l=1;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                l=0;
                                imageView_stky.setAlpha(255);
                            }

                            setMainBottanEditBar();
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();

                        }   
                    }

                });          

                flip = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_flip);
                flip.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {          
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "flip.. in progress",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }

                });
                trash = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img_trash);
                trash.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        try {

                            imageView_stky = (ImageView) catWangMainImgLayout.getChildAt(Info.current_matrix_id+1);
                            imageView_stky.setImageBitmap(null);
                            imageView_stky.setAlpha(255);

                            stickyImage = new ImageView(CatWangMain.this);              
                            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                                    Info.screenWidth, Info.screenWidth);
                            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                            stickyImage.setLayoutParams(params);

                            stickyImage.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt((String)stickyItemId.get(index))));
                            stickyImage.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);

                            sticky_list.add(stickyImage);

                            Bitmap bmap2 = loadBitmapFromView(stickyImage);
                            imageView_stky.setOnTouchListener(null);
                            imageView_stky.setOnTouchListener(onTouchListenerStickImage);
                            imageView_stky.setImageBitmap(bmap2);
                            setSelectStickyMode();
                            Info.addMat(Pinch.matrix, Info.current_matrix_id);              
                            Pinch.editMood = false;

                            Info.sticky_param.set(Info.current_matrix_id,new SavedStickyImageParam(Info.ceterOfX, Info.ceterOfY, Info.widthAfterZoom, Info.rotation));

                            catWangMainImgLayout.removeViewAt(catWangMainImgLayout.getChildCount() - 1);
                            catWangMainImgLayout.invalidate();
                            stickyItemId.remove(index);
                            setSelectStickyMode();

                            sticky_list.remove(index);              
                            Info.sticky_param.remove(index);
                            Info.deleteMat(index);          
                           Info.current_matrix_id = Info.current_matrix_id - 1;  

                            index=index-1;;
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            void setSelectStickyMode() {
                editImage = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_edit);
                editImage.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                rl_mainImageBottamBar1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_bottam_bar);
                rl_mainImageBottamBar1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                rl_mainImageBottamBar2 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rl_bottam_bar2);
                rl_mainImageBottamBar2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                          carHead = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll_catHead);
                carHead.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
                try {

                    BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                    BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o);

                    final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
                    int scale = 1;
                    while (o.outWidth / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE
                            && o.outHeight / scale / 2 >= REQUIRED_SIZE) scale *= 2;
                 BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                    o2.inSampleSize = scale;
                    return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                }
                return null;
            }
        }

        ///////////////////////////////////////

        public class Info {
            static int screenWidth = CatWangMain.width, screenHight, stickyImageID = 90;
            static OnTouchListener onTch;       

            public static ArrayList matrixList;
            public static Point p1;
            public static Point p2;
            public static int ceterOfX, ceterOfY, widthAfterZoom = screenWidth, rotation;
            public static ArrayList sticky_param;//  = new ArrayList();;
            public static int current_matrix_id = -1;


            public static boolean checkPointInRect(float rx, float ry, int rw, int rh, int rot, float px, float py, boolean x){

                double rotRad = (Math.PI * rot) / 180;
                double dx = px - rx;
                double dy = py - ry;

                double h1 = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
                double currA = Math.atan2(dy,dx);

                double newA = currA - rotRad;
                double x2 = Math.cos(newA) * h1;
                double y2 = Math.sin(newA) * h1;

                if (x2 > - 0.5 * rw && x2 < 0.5 * rw && y2 > - 0.5 * rh && y2 < 0.5 * rh)
                    return true;
                    return false;      
            }

            public static void addMat(Matrix m){

                if(matrixList == null){
                    matrixList = new ArrayList();
                }
            }
            public static void addMat(Matrix m, int position){

                    matrixList.set(position, m);

            }
            public static void deleteMat(int pos){        
                matrixList.remove(pos);
            }

            public static Matrix getMat(int pos){

                return (Matrix)matrixList.get(pos);
            }
            public static int getMatrixSize(){
                       return matrixList.size();

            }
        }

        ////////////////////////////////////

        public class Pinch //implements OnTouchListener
        {          
            public static Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            public static Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
            RelativeLayout parent;
            Activity context;         

            static final int NONE = 0;
            static final int DRAG = 1;
            static final int ZOOM = 2;
            int mode = NONE, preRotate, rotate;
            public  int x,y;        

            PointF start = new PointF();
            PointF mid = new PointF();
            float oldDist = 1f;
            private boolean singleTouch;
            public static float scale = 1;
            public static int drag_x_value = Info.screenWidth/2, drag_y_value = Info.screenWidth/2;
            public static boolean editMood;              
            OnTouchListener touchLis = new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                    ImageView view = (ImageView) v;        
                    dumpEvent(event);
                        }else {
                            Info.ceterOfX = (int)mid.x;
                            Info.ceterOfY = (int)mid.y;
                        }              

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

                    return true; // indicate event was handled
                }
            };

            public Pinch(Activity context, RelativeLayout parent) {
                this.context = context;
                this.parent = parent;                  
            }

            public ImageView addImage(Bitmap image, int id) {                   
                matrix = new Matrix();
                ImageView tempImage = new ImageView(context);
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);      
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
                tempImage.setId(Info.stickyImageID);
                Info.stickyImageID = Info.stickyImageID + 1;        
                tempImage.setImageBitmap(image);        
                tempImage.setLayoutParams(params);               
                Info.onTch = touchLis;
                tempImage.setOnTouchListener(Info.onTch);
                matrix.postScale(01.00f, 01.00f);
                tempImage.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);
                tempImage.setImageMatrix(matrix);                  
                Info.ceterOfY = Info.ceterOfX;        
                Info.addMat(Pinch.matrix);
                Info.current_matrix_id = Info.getMatrixSize()-1;
                Info.sticky_param.add(new SavedStickyImageParam(Info.ceterOfX, Info.ceterOfY, Info.widthAfterZoom, Info.rotation));
                parent.addView(tempImage);
                return tempImage;
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the tag by setTag() for each image view then, in On Click Event u can select the image by getTag()..